# RDS SQL Server - error when trying to use Database Email

Tags: sql-server, smtp, amazon-rds, amazon-ses

I am trying to configure Database Email on RDS for SQL Server.
I used this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.DBMail.html
I am using existing, working SES credentials (used currently in EC2 instance)
The outbound security group rule is 0.0.0.0/0

When trying to send a email I get the below error:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 6 (2021-02-25T20:57:01). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond [aws ip]:587).
> )

Any other ideas on this one?

Comment: Are you actually using an IP address for the SES server? That would be unusual. Have a read through this other blog entry to see if you missed a step, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-database-mail-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/

Comment: I used email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com for server. I have read the blog post aswell, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set up a VPC Endpoint
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html#send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints-procedure